# How can i use my custom shader in Linderdaum Engine scene?

Tags: c++, opengl, linderdaum

Currently I replace default.sp with my custom shader and it works fine. But this shader is applied to all objects in the scene.

`Scene->SetMtl()` works only with materials and not OpenGL shaders.

How can I use my custom shader only for some objects?

Comment: This question doesn't have enough information for anyone to be able to answer it.

Comment: Well you just have to unbind the shader?

Comment: @Vallentin: I need to tell the Scene to use my shader in a material only for one object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method `clScene::SetMtlFromShader()` which accepts three `clRenderState` variables. One for each pass: normal, shadow and reflection.

You need to create your own `clRenderState` and set the OpenGL shader program to it using `clRenderState::SetShaderProgram()` method. It should work fine.

Comment: Can I load it from file?